# Specific Registry Key can't be found with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, registry, automated-tests, hp-uft

For a Test automation I have to check if certain Keys are generated in the registry.
By far I have this script:

```
'Registry Path
Const HKCR = &H80000000     'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (0)
Const HKLM = &H80000002     'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (1)

Dim oReg: Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:!root/default:StdRegProv")

'Dim Arrays
Dim RegRootArray(1)
Dim RegMachineArray(6)

Dim CurrentArray()

'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Array
RegRootArray(0) = "AlmBtPgLib.ALMPlugIn.1\CLSID"
RegRootArray(1) = "AlmBtPgLib.ALMPlugIn\CurVer"

'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE Array
RegMachineArray(0) = "SOFTWARE\Macrovision\FlexNet Publisher"
RegMachineArray(1) = "SOFTWARE\Company\SWS\PlugIns\AlmBtPgLib.ALMPlugIn"
RegMachineArray(2) = "SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\FlexNet Licensing Service"
RegMachineArray(3) = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FlexNet Licensing Service"
RegMachineArray(4) = "SOFTWARE\Company\LMS"
RegMachineArray(5) = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\aksfridge"
RegMachineArray(6) = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\hasplms"

'Loop through both Arrays and check Registry
For i = 0 To 1
    If i=0  Then 
        ReDim CurrentArray(UBound(RegRootArray)) 'Copy Values from RegRootArray to CurrentArray
        For arrI1 = LBound(RegRootArray) To UBound(RegRootArray)
            CurrentArray(arrI1) = RegRootArray(arrI1)
        Next
        Key = HKCR
    Else 
        ReDim CurrentArray(UBound(RegMachineArray)) 'Copy Values from RegMachineArray to CurrentArray
        For arrI2 = LBound(RegMachineArray) To UBound(RegMachineArray)
            CurrentArray(arrI2) = RegMachineArray(arrI2)
        Next
        Key = HKLM
    End If

    'Check Keys in Registry
    For Each Path In CurrentArray
        If oReg.EnumKey(Key, Path, arrSubKeys) = 0 Then
            MsgBox(Path & " exist") 'for development
        Else
            MsgBox(Path & " don't exist") 'for development
        End If
    Next
Next
```

For some reason

```
"SOFTWARE\Company\SWS\PlugIns\AlmBtPgLib.ALMPlugIn"
```

is shown as non existing. 
I checked if *PlugIns* or *SWS* "exists". 
None of them do. *Company* does exist.

I checked the registry and the path manually. Both seem to be okay. 
When I create a new Key I can't find it neither. 
 
I restarted the system, no change. 
The return value of EnumKey is 2. Simply 2.

I searched the web but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for your help.
I can't check anything util tomorrow because i leave work for the day.

Update:

When i run the script extern, say as checkReg.vbs it works.
Could it be that UFT somehow has not the right permission? Although both, the .vbs script and UFT run under the same User. 

Cheers
sam

Comment: Perhaps it's a security permission? Have you tried impersonating an administrator? `GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")`

Comment: I tried that. No change

Comment: Short Update:


I Changed the Permission for the said Key, CCleand the registry and turned off UAC.
No Change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scripting or Visual Basic, the method EnumKey returns an integer value that is 0 (zero) if successful. If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code according to Microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Should not you use something like this instead:

```
    Set objReg = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    RegValue = objReg.RegRead(yourregistryentrypath)
```

Comment: Yeah I checked the return value but the value should be 0 or a number that looks something like this 0x8004xxxx but all I get is the value 2.

Comment: I don't want the Value of the Key I just wanna check if it exists.

Comment: and if your key does not have value or not found what does it gives you?

Comment: If i'm searching for a clearly non existing Key i get the return Value 2

Comment: And what does this according to Microsoft means?

Comment: The return Value should be somthing like 0x8004xxxx. The return value 2 shouldn't even exist http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393978(v=vs.85).aspx